# Read and store variables from JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON data with an id no. at the end:

```
[{"Name":"malek","Email":"malek@bar.com","Donation":"5","Type":"Cash","id":0},{"Name":"donnie","Email":"donnie@bar.com","Donation":"6","Type":"Cheque","id":1},{"Name":"ramanuj","Email":"ramanuj@bar.com","Donation":"3","Type":"NEFT","id":2},{"Name":"neha","Email":"neha@bar.com","Donation":"2","Type":"RTGS","id":3},{"Name":"aasha","Email":"aasha@bar.com","Donation":"1","Type":"CC","id":4},{"Name":"zia","Email":"zia@bar.com","Donation":"6","Type":"PayU","id":5},{"Name":"John","Email":"John@bar.com","Donation":"7","Type":"Instamojo","id":6}]
```

I want to specifically get the Email: of John and store it in a variable $johnemail, so that $johnemail == 'John@bar.com'

What could be the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using `json_decode`, `array_column`(available since PHP 5.5) and `array_search` functions:

```
$json_data = '[{"Name":"malek","Email":"malek@bar.com","Donation":"5","Type":"Cash","id":0},{"Name":"donnie","Email":"donnie@bar.com","Donation":"6","Type":"Cheque","id":1},{"Name":"ramanuj","Email":"ramanuj@bar.com","Donation":"3","Type":"NEFT","id":2},{"Name":"neha","Email":"neha@bar.com","Donation":"2","Type":"RTGS","id":3},{"Name":"aasha","Email":"aasha@bar.com","Donation":"1","Type":"CC","id":4},{"Name":"zia","Email":"zia@bar.com","Donation":"6","Type":"PayU","id":5},{"Name":"John","Email":"John@bar.com","Donation":"7","Type":"Instamojo","id":6}]';

$search_name = 'John';
$items = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);
$emails = array_column($items, 'Name', 'Email');   // email is good for using as array key, as it should be unique
$johnemail = array_search($search_name, $emails);  // note that this is case-sensitive search 

print_r($johnemail);  // "John@bar.com"
```

Comment: @DonnieAshok, if it works for you, have you tried to accept the answer?

Comment: I am sorry did not know! New to stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: @DonnieAshok, that's ok

Comment: is there any way to know the number of cells in the email column? @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @DonnieAshok, what do you mean with `the number of cells` ?

Comment: the number of variables in the $emails array.. I am sorry if I sound noob. For example there are 6 email ids in the whole JSON data, can I count them before searching for one.
This would be helpful for using it in a for next loop.

Comment: @DonnieAshok, we know that email should be unique. So, when we do `array_column($items, 'Name', 'Email')` - we are getting the array with `Email` as keys and `Name` as values. Therefore, `count(array_column($items, 'Name', 'Email'))` will give you the number of emails also

Comment: You are just great! Thanks for all the help!